# Path functions for URL

Tags: c#, path

I want to use functions of Path class (`GetDirectoryName`, `GetFileName`, `Combine`,etc.) with paths in URL format with slash (/).

Example of my path:

`"xxx://server/folder1/folder2/file"`

I tried to do the job with `Path` functions and in the end just replaced the separator.

I've found that the `GetDirectoryName` function does not correctly replace the slashes:

`Path.GetDirectoryName(@"xxx://server/folder/file") -> @"xxx:\server\folder"`

Like you see one slash is lost.

How can I cause the Path functions to use the 'alternative' separator?

Can I use another class with the same functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm afraid `GetDirectoryName`, `GetFileName`, `Combine`,etc. use [Path.DirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.directoryseparatorchar.aspx) in the definition and you want [Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.altdirectoryseparatorchar.aspx).

And since Path is a sealed class, I think the only way to go about is string replacement.You can replace `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`('\') with `Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar`('/') and `Path.VolumeSeparatorChar`(':') with ":/"

Answer (score 6):

For `GetDirectoryName()`, you can use

```
pageRoot = uri.Remove(uri.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using a combination of System.Uri, System.UriBuilder, and (if necessary) custom System.UriParser subclass(es)?

Answer (score 0):

If the URI is a local file URI of the form `file://whatever` then you can call `string path = new Uri(whatever).LocalPath` and call the `Path` methods on it. If you cannot guarantee the Uri is to a local path, you cannot guarantee components of the Uri correspond to machines, folders, files, extensions, use directories, separator characters, or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Long time after...I was looking for a solution and found this topic, so i decided to make my (very simple) code

```
string dirRootUpdate = string.Empty;
string fileNameupdate = string.Empty;
string pathToGetUpdate = string.Empty;

string[] _f = Properties.Settings.Default.AutoUpdateServerUrl.Split('/');

for (int i = 0; i < _f.Count() - 1; i++)
{
    dirRootUpdate += _f[i];

    if (i == 0) // is the first one
    {
        dirRootUpdate += "/";
    }
    else if (i != _f.Count() - 2) // not the last one ?
    {
        dirRootUpdate += "/";
    }
}
fileNameupdate = _f[_f.Count() - 1];
```

the setting "Properties.Settings.Default.AutoUpdateServerUrl" contains the string to be verified

Works fine, may require some refination to look better.
Hope could help someone